# settings.gradle as it does not exist

Tags: macos, cordova, android-studio, ionic-framework, ionic3

I lost a week from my life due to this Error, I will be very thinkfull if there is one who can provide a Solution for this problem,

In my Mac Catalina I'm not able to build my Ionic 3 App on Android

I'm losing my mind, Please heeeeelp!!!

```
> ionic cordova build android --prod

> ionic-app-scripts build --prod --target cordova --platform android
[21:20:07]  ionic-app-scripts 3.2.2 
[21:20:07]  build prod started ... 
[21:20:07]  clean started ... 
[21:20:07]  clean finished in 4 ms 
[21:20:07]  copy started ... 
[21:20:08]  deeplinks started ... 
[21:20:08]  deeplinks finished in 19 ms 
[21:20:08]  ngc started ... 
[21:20:21]  ngc finished in 13.22 s 
[21:20:21]  preprocess started ... 
[21:20:21]  preprocess finished in 2 ms 
[21:20:21]  webpack started ... 
[21:20:21]  copy finished in 13.88 s 
[21:20:46]  webpack finished in 25.14 s 
[21:20:46]  uglify started ... 
[21:20:46]  sass started ... 
[21:20:49]  sass finished in 3.18 s 
[21:20:49]  cleancss started ... 
[21:20:53]  cleancss finished in 3.67 s 
[21:21:04]  uglify finished in 18.51 s 
[21:21:04]  postprocess started ... 
[21:21:04]  postprocess finished in 22 ms 
[21:21:04]  lint started ... 
[21:21:04]  build prod finished in 57.03 s 
[21:21:12]  lint finished in 7.06 s 
> cordova build android
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/bruno/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_221.jdk/Contents/Home

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not read settings file '/Users/bruno/Desktop/TMT/Final/tutorial/platforms/android/settings.gradle' as it does not exist. // and Me I say it exists 

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Error: /Users/bruno/.sdkman/candidates/gradle/5.6.3/bin/gradle: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not read settings file '/Users/bruno/Desktop/TMT/Final/tutorial/platforms/android/settings.gradle' as it does not exist. // and Me I say it exists 

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
```

Ionic info

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI          : 5.4.4 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.5
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.2

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 7.1.0
   Cordova Platforms : android 6.3.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.2, (and 4 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.8.0 
   native-run  : not installed

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/bruno/Library/Android/sdk)
   NodeJS            : v10.16.3 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.9.0
   OS                : macOS Catalina
```

For more info when I update cordova to 8 and I remove the platform and add it again, the execution fails with the same error :

I tried with add platform android@6.4.0 also @6.3.0, but the same there is always an issue of this type.

Comment: This sounds like a typical MacOS file system permission issue. Make sure you have taken the required steps to safely run cordova commands without sudo, unfortunately I can't remember which guide I used for that.